# if statement in html (with jinja2) - where should I edit to make it work?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

UPDATE : There was whitespaces in `session['sid']` and that was why this didn't work!

I'm using python, flask, jinja2, html.
This is a part of my html code.

```
    <h1>{{session['sid']}}</h1>                   <!--shows 'admin'-->
    <ul>
        {% if session['sid'] != 'admin' %}
        <li> <a href="/sendmail">SEND MAIL</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="">MAIL BOX</a> </li>
        {% endif %}
```

`session` is a dictionary type data sent to this html from python and I double checked that `session['sid']` is `'admin'`. But those hyperlinks still show up, so it looks like `if` statements doesn't work. Somewhere in the code, there is also `session['sid']!='admin'` which also doesn't work. I googled about  `if`statement example in html, but I don't still understand where I made mistake. Can anybody let me know what I am missing here?

I have tried excluding `'` around `admin` or using `{% if equal session['sid'] 'admin'%}` instead.

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: why not just debug the HTML? Inserting `{{ session['sid'] }}` will display its value and you can then determine whether it is or is not equal to `'admin'`

Comment: @Attack68 edited my code.

Comment: @HarshaB There's no error. Just the if statement doesn't work.

Comment: Can you verify `type(session['sid'])` is a `str`, just in case it's not another type that just stringifies to `admin`?

Comment: @Amadan Thanks for the idea. I added `print(type(session['sid']))` right before it redirects to the above html file, and the type was `<class 'str'>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i tested your template (named as `template.j2`) with `jinja-cli` and this data file (named as `data.json`):

```
{
    "session": {
        "sid": "admin"
    }
}
```

command line:

```
# pip install jinja-cli
# jinja -d data.json template.j2
```

the result is correct:

```
<ul>

</ul>
```

so i think the template is fine; you may want to dump `session` in python code to see if flask really sets its properly; `flask.session` is a proxy; under the hood it is a signed cookie ([`doc`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#sessions)); so you probably should also check your cookie settings;

Comment: Thanks! I added a header to show what is in `session['sid']` as above, and this is getting more frustrating. At least it seems to mean flask sets it properly.

Comment: @PuffedRiceCrackers i'd recommend upload the whole project in that case so that we can see if anything wrong with its configuration;

Comment: In fact, `session['sid']` had whitespaces, something like `admin     `.